# Functional Java: how do I construct an empty list?

Tags: functional-java

I wish to construct the empty list of type `List<String>`. The best I can come up with that satisfies the type-checker is:

```
(List<String>) (Object) List.nil()
```

which is terribly ugly. Is there something better?

Comment: Why don't you use Scala?

Comment: Indeed, why don't I use Haskell? Alas, historical constraints. :-(

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

```
List<String> l = List.<String>nil();
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
List<String> myList = list();
```

Comment: Aha, I see, I'm not allowed to construct it in an anonymous expression context. Thanks!